# Tkintermapview does not works without window.mainloop function

Tags: python, tkinter

I am using a tkinter code which uses a while Loop, and thus i cannot use a window.mainloop() function. I want to use tkintermapview library, but it wont show the map unless window.mainloop() is called. Please help me with this.

I tried using tkintermapview's map_widget inside the while loop but it did not help

Comment: Please refer to this guide on how to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and read about [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Remember, we can't help you if we don't know what you've already tried.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Are you at least calling `window.update_idletasks()` in your loop?  *Nothing* in Tkinter happens by magic, its code has to explicitly be run in order for anything to update onscreen.

Comment: You should never have your own custom loop instead of calling `mainloop`. Why do you think you need a custom loop?